# Instrumenting java string object size gives incorrect result

Tags: java, instrumentation, objectsize

I am using the `java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation` package to calculate the size of a java string. I follow the steps as listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52682/537503) to create a java agent jar. Below is the application code that calls the java agent class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string = "A very long string which I have trimmed for this example";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string);
    for (int i=0; i<16000; i++) {
        sb.append(string);
    }

    printObjectSize(sb.toString());


}

private static long printObjectSize(Object object) {
    final long objectSize = ObjectSizeFetcher.getObjectSize(object);
    System.out.println("Object type: " + object.getClass() + ", size: " + objectSize + " bytes");
    return objectSize;
}
```

Here `ObjectSizeFetcher` is the class in the java agent that calls the instrumentation code internally. Irrespective of how big the string is, I always get the output as

```
Object type: class java.lang.String, size: 24 bytes
```

What could be going wrong?

Comment: who says anything is wrong? the byte size and the length of a String are not the same. there are other things in play as well, for instance the encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A String object doesn't contain the String data but is a wrapper for a byte[] or char[] which contains the actual data.

You need to extract the underlying array and get it's size as well.

The String object should be about 24 bytes.

Comment: Great. Pull out the char array and getting its size gave the right result. Thanks!